# How to apply an operation/functionality on one column during getting data of a table in Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, controller

I want to get all the data of today's Date, but during getting it I want to apply an operation on the data of one column only NOT others. This operation is from another function.

`$data = Net::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();`

I have two options:

1. During getting data, call to that function on the specific column
2. After getting data, put a loop and then apply that operation and save data into new object

In this table, there is a column called **profit**, and I want to **encode** this profit into alphabets by calling **encode_code()** function remaining the other data as it is.

I don't know how I can do this, please help me if anyone knows.

Comment: So you have to encode profit field of the result you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to get each object from the collection and for each of those object,call the desired function.

```
$data = Net::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
foreach($data as $key => $dat)
{
  $data[$key]->profit = encode_code($dat->profit);
}
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call the function and turn it like this

I just didn't know what you wanted to do, so this is my best

```
$data = Net::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();    

foreach($data as $i => $d){
    $data[$i]->profit =  encode_code（$d->profit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could loop through your result and encode each row, but this would prevent you from reusing this code.

Instead you could put that encode function directly into the model, so that you can reuse it everywhere:

```
public function getEncodedProfit() {
    return encode_code($this->profit);
}
```

Now you can just use this function everywhere in your controllers or views like that:

```
echo $net->getEncodedProfit();
```